# Compare two CSV file in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have two CSV file, one is to read the data and another is to compare the data, I am able to read the data from CSV file, now the response which comes from server I want to compare that response in another CSV File.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) which can be applied either to the whole response body:

[image]

or you can compare [2 JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) originating from different CSV files:

[image]

Also you have various comparison options like:

- using regular expressions for "contains" and "matches" modes
- using strings for "substring" mode (don't be confused with "contains" as they're different beasts)
- Checking whether expected and actual result are equal
- Providing more than one expected criteria
- Use clauses like "Not" and "Or"
- etc.

More information: [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved)

Comment: Thank you for a reply Dmitri, In my scenario I want to compare the data which comes from server to the CSV file

Comment: then 1st option is for you

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, You always help me in Jmeter, It solved my problem